# sprintf use without gsub

Tags: r, printf

what is the more elegant way of just using `sprintf` without the `gsub` for this line of code?

```
gsub(" ","0",sprintf("%2.d", 0:15))
[1] "00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
```

i.e. I want the zeros infront of the single digit numbers...as output as characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `0` in the format string to pad with leading zeros instead of spaces: `sprintf("%02d", 0:15)`