# increment leading zero in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format number as fixed width, with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros)
>   [sprintf use without gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379767/sprintf-use-without-gsub)

This has probably been done before but I couldn't find a thread for R.

How would I increment leading zeroes in R?

For example have a **vector** called x with elements: 0001, 0002, 0003....9999

Comment: Looks like it has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379767/sprintf-use-without-gsub . Both found with search: [r] leading zeros

Comment: Just found a third: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros .... yeah, I know... get a life.

Comment: whoops i should prolly delete this then. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can anymore. We can close it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%04s", as.character(1:20))
[1] "0001" "0002" "0003" "0004" "0005" "0006" "0007" "0008" "0009" "0010" "0011" "0012" "0013" "0014" "0015" "0016"
[17] "0017" "0018" "0019" "0020"
```

On Windows I am able to locate an Rhelp posting that says you can get success with

```
head( sprintf("%04d", 1:999)  )
[1] "0001" "0002" "0003" "0004" "0005" "0006"
```

Comment: Whoops, I think I completely misinterpreted this question.

Comment: It's a question I have answered before on Rhelp more than once. I have to look up my earlier answer every time. I keep thinking it should be "%0000s"

Comment: hi DWin, I tried your answer but it's not working for me

`code`> nums = sprintf("%04s", as.character(1:9999)); head(nums)
[1] "   1" "   2" "   3" "   4" "   5" "   6"`code`

There are no leading zeros, just empty spaces

Comment: Ah, then you must be on a different OS (than me on a Mac). The sprintf function calls system facilities. I get the predicted results: tail( sprintf("%04s", as.character(1:999)) )
[1] "0994" "0995" "0996" "0997" "0998" "0999"

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are all 4 digits, then regex could do it:

```
gsub("0(\\d{3})","1\\1",x)
```

More generally:

```
gsub("^0(\\d*)$","1\\1",x)
```